# Using phone gap with a localhost webservice

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-services, cordova

is there anyone who knows how to connect to a localhost webservice using phone gap? because i am using html and javascript only and i created the web service on c# visual studio....Please help anyone  .
The error im getting on my phone is [object Object] and im using the ip address i got from the phonegap loading fix
This is my code for ajax$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();

        url: 'http://192.168.43.11:26606/caterers.asmx/LoginPhoneGap', //26606
        type: 'post',
       // dataType: 'json',
        data: {userEmail: username,
               userPass:password},
        success:function (data) 
        {
            alert(data);


        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, errs) {
            console.log(errs);
            console.log(desc);
            alert(xhr);
            location.reload();
        }
    });


});
```

});

Comment: Hmmm, I'm curious, is this being tested on a device or on a computer? I ask because it seems to me really strange to have an asmx service hosted inside a device... Also, the code you posted is incomplete or totally wrong, there's no ajax call, it's like there are some lines missing.

Comment: its tested on a device ...so what can i do then ? ohh yeah i just forgot the  $(ajax)({..  part